# How can i read pairs (x,y) of numbers from a .txt file separated by commas in java?

Tags: java

for example 
163,15
765,69.9

the 163 and 765 should be stored in one variable (x)
and 15 and 69.9 in another variable (y)

im having a lot of problems in learning java :( 
Thanksss

Comment: Have you learned about `Scanner` for reading input? If so, you know how to read a token, e.g. `163,15`. --- Have you learned about `split()`? If so, you can split on the comma. Alternatively, have you learned about `indexOf()` and `substring()`. If so, you can find the comma, and extract the two substrings.

Answer (score -2):

The following should give you an idea on how to implement this

```
// The following is pseudo code

ArrayList<Float> data; // we will assume this to be [163,15,765,69.9]
                       // you will need to implement and parse this
                       // yourself

ArrayList<Float> tmp1 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Float> tmp2 = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i=0; i<data.size(); i++)
{
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        tmp1.add(data[i]);
    }
    else
    {
        tmp2.add(data[i]);
    }   
}

// We now have something that looks like this
// tmp1 = [163, 765]
// tmp2 = [15, 69.9]
```

Now you just need to form tuples with the following lists.

Comment: The question is about **parsing** pairs of numbers from a text file. Your answer has nothing to do with parsing. *Not useful.*

Comment: IMO, it would make more sense to pair these values together in an object, rather than keeping the components in two separate lists.